# Migrating from aws_api_gateway_rest_api to aws_apigatewayv2_api loose OpenAPI integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I have an AWS API Gateway (REST API) which is deployed through Terraform like that:

```
locals {
  api = templatefile("${path.module}/backend-api/api.json", {
      service-user-management = aws_lambda_function.user-management.invoke_arn
    })
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "backend" {
  name        = "backend-api"
  description = "Backend API"
  body        = local.api

  endpoint_configuration {
    types = ["REGIONAL"]
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "backend" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.backend.id
  stage_name  = "default"

  triggers = {
    redeployment = sha1(join(",", list(
      local.api,
      data.archive_file.user-management.output_base64sha256
    )))
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_settings" "backend" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.backend.id
  stage_name  = aws_api_gateway_deployment.backend.stage_name
  method_path = "*/*"

  settings {
    metrics_enabled = true
    logging_level   = "INFO"
  }
}
```

For reference, `api.json` looks like:

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "",
    "title": ""
  },
  "paths": {
    "/auth": {
      "post": {
        "summary": "User authentication",
        "parameters": [],
        "responses": {
          "400": {
            "description": "Invalid `password`"
          }
        },
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
            "uri": "${service-user-management}",
            "passthroughBehavior": "when_no_match",
            "httpMethod": "POST",
            "type": "aws_proxy"
        }
      }
    },
```

It works well but I want to convert it to API Gateway V2, I have tried that:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "backend" {
  name          = "backend-api-2"
  description = "Backend API"
  protocol_type = "HTTP"
  disable_execute_api_endpoint = false
  version = "v0.1"
  body        = local.api
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_deployment" "backend-default" {
  api_id      = aws_apigatewayv2_route.backend.api_id
  description = "backend deployment"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "backend" {
  api_id    = aws_apigatewayv2_api.backend.id
  route_key = "$default"
}
```

It works well except that none of the endpoints have an integration, no lambda are bound.
What are the correct OpenAPI attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the OpenAPI format may have slightly changed, instead of directly declaring the integration, referring to it worked:

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "",
    "title": ""
  },
  "paths": {
    "/auth": {
      "post": {
        "summary": "User authentication",
        "parameters": [],
        "responses": {
          "400": {
            "description": "Invalid `password`"
          }
        },
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
          "$ref": "#/components/x-amazon-apigateway-integrations/user-management"
        }
      }
...
    },
    "x-amazon-apigateway-integrations": {
      "user-management": {
            "uri": "${service-user-management}",
            "passthroughBehavior": "when_no_match",
            "httpMethod": "POST",
            "type": "aws_proxy"
        }
      }
    }
```